# Typed Racket Optimizer

Tags: compiler-optimization, typed-racket

I am learning some Typed Racket at the moment and i have a somewhat philosophical dilemma:

Racket claims to be a language development framework and Typed Racket is one such languages implemented on top of it. The documentation mentions that due to types being used, the compiler now can do more/better optimizations.

The concrete question:

Where do these optimizations happen?

1) In the compile/expand part (which is "programmable" as part of the language building framework)

-or-

2) further down the line in the (bytecode) optimizer (which is written in C and not directly modifieable via the framework).

If 2) is true, does that mean the type information is lost after the compile/expand stage and later "rebuilt/guessed" by the optimizer or has the intermediate representation been altered to to accomodate the type information and inform later stages about them?

The reason i am asking this specific question is because i want to get a feeling for how general the Racket language framework really is, i.e. is also viable for statically typed languages without any modifications in the backend versus the type system being only a front-end thing, while the code at runtime is still dynamically typed (but statically checked of course).

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typed Racket's optimizations occur during macro expansion. To see for yourself, you can change `#lang typed/racket` to `#lang typed/racket #:no-optimize`, which shows Typed Racket is in complete control of what optimizations are applied.

The optimizations consist of using type information to replace various uses of certain procedures with  [their unsafe equivalents](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/unsafe.html?q=vector-ref). The unsafe procedures perform no runtime checks on the types of their arguments and cause undefined behavior (read: segfaults) if used incorrectly. You can find out more in the documentation section entitled [Optimization in Typed Racket](http://docs.racket-lang.org/ts-guide/optimization.html?q=typed%20racket%20optimize).

The exposure of the unsafe variants of procedures is what really makes it possible for user-defined languages to implement these optimizations. For example, if you wrote your own language with a type system that could prove vectors were never accessed with out-of-bounds indices you could replaces uses of [`vector-ref`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/vectors.html?q=vector-ref#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._vector-ref%29%29) with [`unsafe-vector-ref`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/unsafe.html?q=vector-ref#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Funsafe%2Fops..rkt%29._unsafe-vector-ref%29%29).

There are similar optimizations that occur at the bytecode level, but these mostly apply when the JIT can infer type information that's not visible at macro expansion time. These are not user-controlled, but you don't have to rely on them.

Comment: This answers everything i wanted to know! Thx!